# regex query nth match

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regrex that matches only  the 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th, 15th, 18th,..... etc of the word "blah" in the following text and ignores the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 5th, 7th, 8th,.... etc. The regex should  match the 3x occurrences only of blah

```
The Band blah The Band blah  blah Up On Cripple Creek (2000 Digital Remaster) blah 2000 blah Greatest Hits blah The Band blah  blah The Weight (2000 Digital Remaster) blah 2003 blah Rhythm Of The Rain blah The Cascades blah  blah Rhythm Of The Rain (LP Version) blah 2005 blah Chronicle Volume One blah Creedence Clearwater Revival blah  blah Who'll Stop the Rain blah 1976 blah The Complete Sun Singles, vol. 1 blah Johnny Cash blah  blah I Walk the Line blah 2001 blah Greatest Hits blah Bob Seger blah  blah Against The Wind blah 1980 blah Their Greatest Hits blah The Eagles blah  blah Lyin' Eyes blah 1975 blah Johnny Horton's Greatest Hits blah Johnny Horton blah  blah North To Alaska
```

Thanks in advance.

FYI, I will be using this regex in Hive

Comment: What's your goal? Getting the indexes, replacing them ..?

Comment: to split on the string using http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFSplit.java

Comment: Too lazy to read all of this, but I assume you want to catch only the "blah" and nothing else, as that would chunk too much.

Comment: Yes, catching only blah at the 3x locations e.g. (3,6,9,12,15,18,21,25, .....) and don't catch the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Nice and compact:

```
(?:blah.*?){2}(blah)
```

Comment: regexpal    the link is too long to copy it here

Comment: Can you bitly/tinyurl the link?

Comment: All "blah"s  and the text between three "blah"s were matched. My goal is only to match  the 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th "blah"s

Comment: Note that only the last `blah` has capturing parens. Regexpal doesn't show you capture groups, but you would (in an actual app) use only the last capture group.

Comment: This is not what I want but Thanks anayways for your effort ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
'(?:(?:.+?)blah(?:.+?)blah(?:.+?)(blah))'
```

This should work, though I'm not sure if regex is the best solution for very long texts

Edited to avoid the first capturing... though it's clear the OP don't get how regexpal works

Comment: That's not my regex, the '+'s are missing (and it works with'em). Do you understand what you're doing? The tools you're using? You should give 'split' a try.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't think both previous answers are what you want (from what you said in the comments), I shall put my stamp here too.
**Disclaimer:** I don't think there is any efficient way to catch only the 3rd blah, but still, you can do it.
**Step 1:** reverse the string, you will need arbitrary-length lookbehind, which you can't have. But you shall have them by reversing the string and using arbitrary-length lookahead.
**Step 2:** the regex below should catch what you want:

```
/halb(?=(?:(?:[^h]|h(?!alb))*halb){2}(?:[^h]|h(?!alb)|halb(?:(?:[^h]|h(?!alb))*halb){2})*$)/
```

**Step 3:** try to reorder/reverse...

(Note: as I'm extremely sleepy, I haven't tested it, and would correct it if needed in a few hours...)

**Edit:**
Ok, now corrected. So it works, but you still have the string backward. You'd have to reverse all the string in your array, and then your array. But still, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/kJUMM/). Once again, if you have performance problems, you may want to try playing with possessive quantifiers if you can.

Comment: Ok I'll dig into it when I have some free time. (After a quick test, it matches the 3th, 4th, 5th and so on... I'll check why later).

Comment: @user1309258 see my edit. Still some work to do on the result though.